# Hide command and get only output in shell

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker, shell, goose

I am working on pressly/goose tool for migration.
All my commands run from shell script file inside docker container. I wanted to hide certain command or password from the console output logs.

Here is the command,

`goose postgres "user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable" status`

I have tried `stty -echo | command | stty echo` this also.

Is there any way to hide command/password and only shows the output of that command?

Comment: What is the pipe doing? I would write `stty -echo; command; stty echo`, though instead of the semicolon, writing the 3 commands on separate lines would probably make more sense.

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well, but of no use

Comment: Now this makes me think: When you run a shell script, usually none of the commands is printed. Do you happen to have `set -x` turned on in your script? This would indeed reveal the commands being executed. If this is not a case, show a screenshot which demonstrates, how you invoke the script, and how the output looks like.